# what is a Backbone model.save( ) call expecting on a POST operation?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm calling save() on a backbone model to do a POST operation on the back-end. The operation completes successfully server-side (I can see the record added and the response status comes back as 200). Currently the RESTful api call is returning the ID of the inserted record in the response body. I have success and error callbacks defined that I pass to the save call, but success is never called. Instead, the Backbone code is choking on that ID that gets returned from the REST call. Is there a better way for me to handle this from the client end or should the REST api implementation be returning something else?

Comment: @kinakutta Is the success,error callbacks required for adding model saved on server to the collection Or it is handled by default?

Comment: The callbacks aren't required. If you want to periodically sync your client-side model with the server there are explicit method calls to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default I believe it expects the changed properties of the object as JSON. See: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, so I guess I'm wondering then how I could get around this expectation (if I can't get the api to return something different.)

Comment: @kinakuta Updated my answer just a second ago. The changed values might be enough. I've usually sent the whole object though.

Comment: So I guess even in that instance, it still needs an object back which should include the ID. Either way, it looks like the api needs to return something different (or at least return the id in an object that backbone can process).

Comment: Ok, figured out a way around it = override the model's parse method to take the raw reponse and marshal it into an object. Thanks, ponzao.